# Implement a simple IFindSaga

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus, saga

I have a simple `IFindSaga` implemented, I referred and followed the same steps that was provided in particular software document for SQL Persistence Saga Finding Logic. I'm getting an error at `session.GetSagaData<SagaData>` stating that: "`SynchronizedStorageSession` does not contain a definition for `GetSagaData` and no extension method `GetSagaData` accepting a first argument of type `SynchronizedStorageSession` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)." Please help me to solve this.

This is my code where I have implemented `IFindSaga`

```
public class TrackerFind : IFindSagas<SagaData>.Using<ITrackerData>
        {
            public Task<SagaData> FindBy(ITrackerData message, SynchronizedStorageSession session, ReadOnlyContextBag context)
            {
                return session.GetSagaData<SagaData>(
                    context: context,
                    whereClause: "JSON_VALUE(Data,'$.PaymentTransactionId') = @propertyValue",
                    appendParameters: (builder, append) =>
                    {
                        var parameter = builder();
                        parameter.ParameterName = "propertyValue";
                        parameter.Value = message.TrackerID;
                        append(parameter);
                    });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you following this? https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/blob/master/samples/saga/sql-sagafinder/SqlPersistence_2/EndpointSqlServer/OrderSagaFinder.cs

Comment: https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/sql-sagafinder/

Do you have all the needed references?

Comment: Note that the code snippets in the NServiceBus documentation have a "Copy usings" option on them that can help for things like this. Also, custom saga finders is a very out-of-the-way feature of NServiceBus, so we (I work for Particular Software) would be very interested in hearing your specific use case for using a custom saga finder here, instead of having the PaymentTransactionId as your normal correlation property.

Comment: I have added reference and namespace that was mentioned in the Particular software but still the same error exist. @SeanFarmar

Comment: @DavidBoike I'm just trying to learn about `IFindSagas`. It would be helpful if you could provide link for simple example source code along with explanation for every step (since I have only a basic knowledge in C#).

Comment: Can you share your code somehow? (github, bitbucket, dropbox?)

Comment: @Leo Do you mean a sample like this? : https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/saga-finding

Comment: @Sean Farmar I used the following code sample provided in the particular software [code sample link](https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/sql-sagafinder/).

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt yes a similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

"GetSagaData" is an extension method which is part of "NserviceBus" namespace.
include following statement

```
using NServiceBus;
```

This worked for me. I am not getting that error now

Answer (score -2):

use nuget

> package NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql